# Do CircleCasts return the hit point on the collider or the center point of the circle when it hits a collider?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to figure out how exactly RaycastHit2D works when returning values. I want to send a circle cast and return how far the circle went before it hit a collider, but I don't know if RaycastHit2D.distance returns how far the circle traveled or how far away the exact collision point is from the origin. I've looked everywhere and can't seem to find a clear answer.

Comment: This question isn't about using the Visual Studio application, so I've removed that tag for you. Note that you can click on a tag to view more information and its usage guidelines.

Comment: second is true. distance between hit and ray start position

Answer (score 0):

Just make a test, it's how far the circle traveled.

[image: CircleCast]

The circlecast is from the red square.

The length of the green line is the returned `RaycastHit2D.distance`